# Single quote represented by double single quotes not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, escaping

I have the following sql query

```
set @st = @st + ' locationcity=''St. John''s'' order by datet desc'; execute(@st);
```

I used double single quotes because that the way to use single quote in query.

But I am getting following error

> Incorrect syntax near 's'.
>
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' order by datet desc'.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: the error might not be in the statement you provided. What is the initial value of @st before this statement?

Comment: Note: you don't need ; at the end of sql statement.

Comment: Just escape ' by '. e.g:  'St. John''s'

Answer (score 1):

try this:

Use `Print` for debugging

```
Declare @st varchar(1000)='';
set @st=@st+' locationcity=''St. John''''s'' order by datet desc';
print @st
 execute(@st);
```

Answer (score 1):

your resultant query is

```
 locationcity='St. John's' order by datet desc
```

you can see that second last ' before s is considered an closing quote, and hence gives you an error and the next ' act as opening quote without a closing quote and hence one more error.
try

```
''St. John''''s''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 set @st = @set+' locationcity=''St. John''''s'' order by datet desc'
 execute(@st);
```

see this example.

```
 create table #tab (name varchar(50))
 insert into #tab values('hello1')
 declare @set as varchar(max)
 set @set='update #tab '
 set @set=@set+'set name=''john''''s''' --updating name with john's
  exec(@set)
 select * from #tab
```